# Can't get autotest running with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests

Not sure what's going on, but I can't get autotest to work with rails 3. I'm using ruby 1.9.2-head and Rails 3.0.0 and I have all of the relevant gems installed. I'm declaring them in my gemfile like this:

```
group :development do 
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent'
end
```

When I try to run the autotest command I'm getting the following error:
    enter code here`Error loading Autotest style autotest/rails_rspec2 (no such file to load -- autotest/rails_rspec2). Aborting.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem rspec-rails is now at least at beta22, and while it had problems with autotest it should now be fixed. I can run autotest without having to do `bundle exec`. So you should adapt your gemfile to allow using the latest version.

So write something like

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.18"
  gem "autotest"
end
```

The `autotest-rails` is no longer needed.

Comment: I updated my gemfile as you said, and I also updated all of my gems system wide. But it's still not working. I'm getting an even nastier error message: /Users/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1062: warning: method redefined; discarding old gem

Comment: I'm using RVM, not sure if this is causing an issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out that I can run "bundle exec autotest" instead of just "autotest" and it works, but I have no idea why this is.

Comment: It is because you're autotest app is bundled inside of bundler. So it has no executable from the command line. Only through bundler.